# Is it safe to store secrets in serverless.yml?

Tags: serverless, serverless-framework, aws-serverless, aws-secrets-manager

I am working with aws free tier account and amazon charges us for custom secrets. I am creating a lambda function that needs access to secrets. I came across [this](https://seed.run/blog/how-to-manage-secrets-for-your-serverless-app.html) post on how to manage secrets in serverless. Can someone please help me understand if approach 1 of storing it in local is safe? Further is it safe to just put them in yml file if you are not going to check it in anywhere.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by safe? I work for banks, and I wouldn't consider that safe. If you're working on a home project, and you've got a reliable secure backup of the secrets, and you're not going to check them into public github, then why not?

Comment: I was wondering if anyone can snoop on secrets at time of deploying or is it end to end encrypted?

Answer (score 0):

It is a valid approach, however, not recommended in the long run for production systems as it has a few potential issues:

- secrets need to be stored on your local machine, if your machine gets compromised, so are your secrets
- they are stored in plaintext in generated CloudFormation template, if someone gets access to that template, they will be able to use them. Please keep in mind that generated CF template gets stored in an S3 bucket in plaintext, which means that in the end you'll be storing your secrets unencrypted in an S3 bucket

Though, if it's just your personal project, that approach should work just fine for you and will be relatively safe.

The recommended way to do it though is to fetch and decrypt the secrets at runtime, as described in #4 of the cited article.

Comment: The recommended way to do it is to dynamically generate secrets at runtime and inject them into your application (which is authenticated via a number of factors) via a memory-mapped encrypted filesystem, and to make those secrets single-use and short-lived (c.5s). (cf. Hashicorp Vault)